# C++ Async Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm very confused with `std::thread` and `std::async`. Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::vector<int> myvector = {};
std::mutex mu;
int result;

void samplefunc(int a, int& result){
    result = 2 * a;
}

void func1(){
    while(true){
        std::unique_lock locker(mu);
        locker.lock();
        std::vector<int> temp = myvector;
        locker.unlock();
        if(myvector.size() > 0){
            samplefunc(myvector.at(0),result);
            myvector.clear();
        }else{
            samplefunc(0,result);
        }
    }
}

void func2(){
    while(true){
        //do complex things, suppose after complex calculations we have result dummy which is type int
        int dummy = 0;
        std::unique_lock locker(mu);
        locker.lock();
        myvector.push_back(dummy);
        locker.unlock();
    }
}

int main(){
    std::thread t1(func1);
    std::thread t2(func2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

What I want to do is very simple. We have two threads which should run in parallel (i.e. they don't have to wait on each other). However, thread `t1` is supposed to change its behaviour if thread `t2` puts some integer in a shared vector. Does the code given above achieve this, or should we use `std::async`, `std::future`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the shared data is properly synchronized, it is fine for modification from one thread on the shared data to affect computation using that data in separate thread.
But you haven't locked myvector sufficiently. The lock has to surround all reading steps on the shared data. In func1, you release the lock too soon.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that since I clear the vector outside the lock, I should put unlock after clear process. So there is no need for std::async, right?

Comment: @eet you shouldn't be locking/unlocking manually at all. `unique_lock`'s constructor locks the mutex, and its destructor unlocks it. In fact, your manual `lock()` should be throwing an exception since `unique_lock` can't have multiple locks at a time.

Comment: @eet let `std::unique_lock`s constructor take the lock. You don't need to do it manually. If you want to scope the locking duration you can use a block

Comment: @Mgetz thanks for pointing out. Sorry, there should be no locker.lock() at all. Just locker.unlock() is sufficient.

Comment: @eet even that is unnecessary, you can just use a standard block to expire the lock. The lock's destructor will release the mutex

Comment: @eet To your comment, "So there is no need for std::async, right?" Response: I'm not certain I followed the design intent of your code. Be that as it may, on the face of it, your use of std::thread is not problematic to me. (Nowadays, I would usually use std::jthread). You are correct to want to understand how things like std::async and std::future can help you write cleaner code. Particularly, std::future is good when you want to wait on another thread producing a result.